# Getting NULL for empty values in ModelDriven

Tags: java, struts2, url-parameters, ognl, model-driven

`ModelDriven` returns `NULL` for the `params` which have empty values.

**Bean:**

```
public class MyBean
{
    private String userName;
    public void setUserName(String userName)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getUserName()
    {
        return userName;
    }
}
```

**Class:**

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<MyBean>
{
    MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
    public String execute()
    {
        System.out.println(myBean.getUserName());//getting null here
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

**Request:**

`/home/MyAction.do?userName=&pass=`

Hear I am passing empty value for `userName` param but in action I getting the `null` value.

How to get exact value in `ModelDriven`?

Comment: these are not empty values, empty values should be `userName=""&pass=""`

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi When using `request.getParameter("userName")` it will return the proper value ( empty value ).

Comment: Don't create instance of bean by yourself in action. Remove `= new MyBean()`.

Answer (score 0):

When your bean property contains a `null` value it keeps the value in the OGNL expressions and `value` tag. You can always use OGNL expression to evaluate `null` value. For example

```
<s:if test="userName == null">
  <s:property value="username"/>
</s:if>
```

If you want to pass `null` value as a parameter then you should use `null` string.

```
/home/MyAction.do?userName="null"&pass="null"
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, `HttpServletRequest#getParameter()` handles the two cases differently; for most practical purposes, it shouldn't matter much. That's because using *${EL}* expressions or *Struts* display tags, the `null` values would get rendered as blanks only.

If, however, you have some code that depends on it (like `?chrome` telling the browser type) you're better off changing it (to something like `?browser=ff`) because making your *Actions* `ServletRequestAware` is not worth it.

If you would still like to go for it, here's how to do it:

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<MyBean>,
                                                       ServletRequestAware
{
    HttpServletRequest request;
    MyBean myBean = new MyBean();

    public String execute()
    {
        if (myBean.getUserName() == null) {
            myBean.setUserName(getRequest().getParameter("userName"));
        }

        System.out.println(myBean.getUserName());
        return "SUCCESS";
    }

    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        this.request = request;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting null values beacuse of

You are implementing `ModelDriven<MyBean>` interface.

and this interface there must override `getModel()` method, check what getModel() method is returning.whether it is returning null or your bean(myBean)variable ..

```
public MyBean getModel() {
return null; // This must be the reason, you will get null always when you call getProperties of bean
}
```

Try like this

```
public MyBean getModel() {
    return myBean ; // This will return your bean in modelDriven Interface(return your bean variable here )
    }
```

Hope it helps.